# Getting an error, "Operator '-=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

Alright so I have this basic line of code,

```
transform.position -= new Vector2(-1f, 0f);
```

and for some reason I'm getting this error,

```
Operator '-=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'
```

I heard this error is about the compiler *not knowing which vector you are specifying*, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to *specify* what `transform.position` is.

Comment: What is the type of `.position` ?

Comment: If `position` is defined as `Vector3` then how would you propose to subtract a `Vector2` from it?